# Adding rows manually to StreamingHttpResponse (Django)

Tags: python, django, csv

I am using Django's StreamingHttpResponse to stream a large CSV file on the fly. According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse), an iterator is passed to the response's `streaming_content` parameter:

```
import csv
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

def get_headers():
    return ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']

def get_data(item):
    return {
        'field1': item.field1,
        'field2': item.field2,
        'field3': item.field3,
    }

# StreamingHttpResponse requires a File-like class that has a 'write' method
class Echo(object):
    def write(self, value):
        return value


def get_response(queryset):
    writer = csv.DictWriter(Echo(), fieldnames=get_headers())
    writer.writeheader() # this line does not work

    response = StreamingHttpResponse(
        # the iterator
        streaming_content=(writer.writerow(get_data(item)) for item in queryset),
        content_type='text/csv',
    )
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=items.csv'

    return response
```

My question is: how can I manually write a row on the CSV writer? manually calling writer.writerow(data) or writer.writeheader() (which also internally calls writerow()) does not seem to write to the dataset, and instead only the generated / streamed data from streaming_content is written on the output dataset.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is yielding results with a generator function instead of calculating them on the fly (within StreamingHttpResponse's `streaming_content` argument) and using the pseudo buffer we created (Echo Class) in order to write a row to the response:

```
import csv
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

def get_headers():
    return ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']

def get_data(item):
    return {
        'field1': item.field1,
        'field2': item.field2,
        'field3': item.field3,
    }

# StreamingHttpResponse requires a File-like class that has a 'write' method
class Echo(object):
    def write(self, value):
        return value

def iter_items(items, pseudo_buffer):
    writer = csv.DictWriter(pseudo_buffer, fieldnames=get_headers())
    yield pseudo_buffer.write(get_headers())

    for item in items:
        yield writer.writerow(get_data(item))

def get_response(queryset):
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(
        streaming_content=(iter_items(queryset, Echo())),
        content_type='text/csv',
    )
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=items.csv'
    return response
```

Comment: Although it looks odd, this answer is the right one among many many answers given on the same subject. Odd that this is so obscured to create a streaming download in Django...

Comment: Good solution but I will change the:
`yield pseudo_buffer.write(get_headers())` for:
`yield pseudo_buffer.writerow(get_headers())` 
in order to write in the next line in the file and to avoid write this `['field1', 'field2', 'field3']` as header, when the rigth header would be `'field1', 'field2', 'field3'`.
You see the `pseudo_buffer.write(...)` write the raw parameter that you pass through.

Comment: Thank you very much for this response. Super helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

The proposed solution can actually lead to incorrect/mismatched CSVs (header mismatched with data). You'd want to replace the affected section with something like:

```
header = dict(zip(fieldnames, fieldnames))
yield writer.writerow(header)
```

instead. This is from the implementation of `writeheader` https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/08045391a7aa87d4fbd3e8ef4c852c2fa4e81a8a/Lib/csv.py#L141:L143

For some reason, it's not behaving well with `yield`

Hope this helps someone in the future :)

Also note that no fix is needed if using python 3.8+ because of this PR: https://bugs.python.org/issue27497

Answer (score 0):

you can chain generator using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertool-functions) in python to add header row to the queryset row

here is how you do it:

```
import itertools

def some_streaming_csv_view(request):
    """A view that streams a large CSV file."""
    # Generate a sequence of rows. The range is based on the maximum number of
    # rows that can be handled by a single sheet in most spreadsheet
    # applications.
    headers = [["title 1", "title 2"], ]
    row_titles = (header for header in headers) # title generator

    items = Item.objects.all()
    rows = (["Row {}".format(item.pk), str(item.pk)] for item in items)
    pseudo_buffer = Echo()
    writer = csv.writer(pseudo_buffer)
    rows = itertools.chain(row_titles, rows)  # merge 2 generators
    return StreamingHttpResponse(
        (writer.writerow(row) for row in rows),
        content_type="text/csv",
        headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'},
    )
```

and you will get csv with the title and the queryset:

```
title 1, title 2
1, 1
2, 2
...
```